# I want to show specific parent terms child term with post list

Tags: custom-post-types

Is there a way I can list all posts in a specific parent terms under child term with 5 post list.

For example;

parent terms (specific By id or slug)

- Child term Name
- - post Title
- - post Title
- - post Title
- - post Title
- - post Title
- Child term Name
- - post Title
- - post Title
- - post Title
- - post Title
- - post Title

Please Help Me...

[image: This is My Custom Category (Terms)]

[image: I want to Show just this thing]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the wordpress in build function

`get_page_hierarchy( $posts, $parent )`

Reference URL : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_hierarchy